# Non-Capturing and Capturing Groups - The right way

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to match an array of elements preceeded by a specific string in a line of text. For Example, match **all pets** in the text below:

> fruits:apple,banana;**pets:cat,dog,bird**;colors:green,blue

`/(?:pets:)(\w+[,|;])+/g**`

Using the given regex I only could match the last word "bird"

Can anybody help me to understand the right way of using Non-Capturing and Capturing Groups?

Thanks!

Comment: How about `/pets:([^;]*)/`?

Comment: what language is your regex for?

Comment: You can't capture each pet in a separate group, because you only have 1 group. What you *can* do is to capture all of them in the same group like `pets:((?:\w+[,;])+)`.

Comment: What is the regex flavor? You should get what you need using [`pets:(?:(\w+)(?:[,;]|$))+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=pets%3a%28%3f%3a%28%5cw%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5b%2c%3b%5d%7c%24%29%29%2b&i=fruits%3aapple%2cbanana%3bpets%3acat%2cdog%2cbird%3bcolors%3agreen%2cblue) in .NET regex by accessing Group 1 capture collection, else, in PCRE, Java, Onigmo, you may rely on `\G`, [`(?:\G(?!^)(?:[,;]|$)|pets:)(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/l2Soxd/1) (and get Group 1 value).

Comment: I'm currently using PCRE and the goal was to get each pet in a match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to have each pet in a separate match and you are using PCRE `\G` is, as suggested by Wiktor, a decent option:

```
(?:pets:)|\G(?!^)(\w+)(?:[,;]|$)
```

Explanation:

- 1st Alternative `(?:pets:)` to find the start of the pattern
- 2nd Alternative `\G(?!^)(\w+)(?:[,;]|$)`

  - `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match
  - Negative Lookahead (?!^) to assert that the Regex does not match at the start of the string
  - `(\w+)` to matches the pets
  - Non-capturing group `(?:[,;]|$)` used as a delimiter (matches a single character in the list `,;` (case sensitive) or `$` asserts position at the end of the string

Perl Code Sample:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = 'fruits:apple,banana;pets:cat,dog,bird;colors:green,blue';
my $regex = qr/(?:pets:)|\G(?!^)(\w+)(?:[,;]|$)/mp;
my @result = ();

while ( $str =~ /$regex/g ) {
    if ($1 ne '') {
        #print "$1\n";
        push @result, $1;
    }
}
print Dumper(\@result);
```

Answer (score 7):

First, let's talk about capturing and non-capturing group:

- (?:...)  non-capturing version, you're looking for this values, but don't need it
- ()       capturing version, you want this values! You're searching for it

So:

(?:pets:) you searching for "pets" but don't want to capture it, after that point, you WANT to capture (if I've understood):

So try (?:pets:)([a-zA-Z,]+); ... You're searching for "pets:" (but don't want it !) and stop at the first ";" (and don't want it too).

Result is : 
Match 1 : cat,dog,bird

A better solution exists with 1 match == 1 pet.

Comment: `(?:pets)` is equivalent to `pets`.